# Como esconder uma div que está dentro de um iframe

Tags: javascript, html

Como eu posso remover/esconder uma div que está dentro de um site num `iframe`, utilizando uma classe para identificar a div, já que na mesma não tem um id.

Exmplo de código:

```html
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Teste de Código</title>
    <style>
        *, *::before, *::after{margin: 0; padding: 0;}
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <IFRAME id="framesrc" src="http://earth.cinego.unaux.com/teste.php" sandbox="allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation" FRAMEBORDER=0 MARGINWIDTH=0 MARGINHEIGHT=0 SCROLLING=NO  style="overflow:hidden;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;height:101%;width:100%;position:fixed;top:0px;left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px" height="100%" width="100%"></IFRAME>


</body>
</html>
```

Dentro desse site que vai carregar no `iframe` existe uma `div` com a `class` `jw-logo`, preciso que essa `div` fique escondida, utilizando a `class` para identificar a `div`.

Comment: Por favor, tente **[edit]** a sua pergunta para adicionar um exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável. Saiba mais [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) e [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6252/69296).

Comment: @LuizFelipe fiz a correção e adicionei um exemplo de código.